# how to get meaningful words from text using stanford nlp in java

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

i have some requirement that is getting meaningful words from parsed text using stanford nlp in java.
i am trying following sample code.

```
    import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
    public class Demo 
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
     LexicalizedParser lp = new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser");
     lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "80","-retainTmpSubcategories"});
                String sent = "my name is arjun";
                Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(sent);
                List taggedWords = parse.taggedYield();
                System.out.println(parse.toString());
    }
    }
```

output:

```
(ROOT (S (NP (PRP$ my) (NN name)) (VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (JJ arjun)))))
```

required output:

```
name,arjun.
```

how to do this.please suggest me.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Determine which phrase levels you are interested in and output only the Word part of the TaggedWord.

From your only example, it seems you are interested in single nouns (NN) and either adjectives (JJ) or ADJP (adjective phrase). (Although based on your example, equally valid answers would be, "show all words starting with an [a] or an [n]" or all words with a length > 2).

You should not use the `toString` version for this; examine the tag values in the parsed tree instead.